# Eclipse, importing maven project errors in installing m2e connectors

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, m2eclipse

On my Ubunutu 18.04 system with JDK-11.0.2, I am using Spring Tool Suite 4  (Version: 4.3.2.RELEASE) to import an existing maven project that freshly cloned from remote repository.

During the installation process, I am facing these errors that I do not know where to begin to debug and solve the problem.

[image]

- For the maven build error, I chose `Select Auto` and pressed finish
- Previously for adding SSL to tomcat `server.xml`, I did create a `.keystore` at the root of the system
- The PKIX error also happened when I wanted to update the ToolSuit (Eclipse).

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Supposing accessing via http instead of https ..using wrong certificate ....

Comment: @khmarbaise, Thanks for the response, would you please tell how I should define what cert it should use, or in general where the certs are stored and defined? is it Eclipse specific problem or the OS?